# How to make the corresponding text bold depending on the URL visited/link clicked in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I have this rather primitive issue, but I have no idea how to solve this:

I have a side hierarchy menu in one of many Razor pages and for now I just manually make the current page bold in the HTML.

- Is there a possibility to automate this?
- What's the best approach for giving the state of the current page?
- Does ASP.NET Core have an integrated function/etc for this?

Here's how my side menu looks like:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 side-menu" style="">
      <ul id="menu-map" class="menu" style="">
          <li class=""><a href="/test1" aria-current="page">
            <span>TEST1</span>
          </a></li>        
          <li class=""><a href="/test2" aria-current="page">
            <span>test2</span>
          </a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/test3" aria-current="page">
            <span>test3</span>
          </a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/test4" aria-current="page">
            <span>test4</span>
          </a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/test5" aria-current="page">
            <span><strong>test5</strong></span>
          </a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

`col-sm-2` is a Bootstrap 4 class, yes.

## Another ELI5 example:

In the side menu above if I click on TEST1 the TEST1 gets bold text, if I click on test2, test2 gets bold text on that page. (/test1 and /test2 correspondently)

A CSS solution might kind of work, but what if the user gets a link to one of the pages? Hence a pure CSS solution is not viable in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does ASP.NET Core have an integrated function/etc for this?

It seems no such build-in function to achive this client side requirement.

Once you click the link, it will redirect to another page and lose the state of the anchor tag. So you can use `localStorage` to store the selected anchor tag's index. And add the `font-weight: bold` class to selected link:

```
<head>      
    <style>           
          .active{
                font-weight: bold;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var data = localStorage.getItem("index");
        if(data!=null)
        {
            $('ul li').eq(data).addClass('active');
        }
    })
    $("#menu-map").find('a').click(function () {
        var str = $(this).parents("li").index();
        localStorage.setItem("index",str);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing if a user gets a link to one of the subpages, the text would not be bold unless the user clicks on any other or the same subpages links?

Comment: Do you mean the text is not bold when a user comes into one of the page without clicking the link?

Comment: that's exactly what I meant by that